# Is there any way to change themes on Google Reader?

Tags: google-reader

It seems that a few important google apps already offer theme customization. Is there any way to change the theme on Google Reader as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not possible to change the layout only through user scripts or Reader Play.

The most promising one for me is [Helvetireader](http://helvetireader.com/)

Answer (score 8):

You could style at least the sidebar for this session with a ninja design [if you press](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konami_code)
<kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>.

Comment: Neo you rock my socks off.

Answer (score 4):

[Better GReader](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6424/)

This Firefox extension is pretty good. It offers a few different themes, plus several other enhancements.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Google Reader - Colorful List View](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/8782) `Greese Monkey Script`. Pretty good.
[image]
<sub>(source: [lifehacker.com](http://cache.lifehacker.com/assets/resources/2008/06/colorizegreader.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

[Feedly](http://www.feedly.com/) is not a theme but an alternate view of your GReader, accessible through a Firefox or Chrome plugin

Answer (score 0):

There's also [Re-Reader](http://johnholdun.com/re-reader/), a bookmarklet which restyles the web interface giving you a more simplistic look.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [sublime reader extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/jbhkdhkngalchoobjfiobbjobnbpfgmg) for Google chrome. Comes with two themes, dark and light!

Answer (score 0):

https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/google-redesigned/

like this pretty much, very modern and nerdy grey look